# Why is the entry in the state deleted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to do something very simple but I do not understand why it not working for me

so i have a component that include the details about the user are logged in
and i want to request the details user and put them in the component

so I do a axios.get to my back-end i get the detail set them in the state with success put them in the component but when I refresh the page i get state is undefined

I add here the code

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import './account.css'



function Account(props) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    const [currentPass, setCurrentPass] = useState()
    const [newPass, setNewPass] = useState()
    const [confirmPass, setConfirmPass] = useState()



    let navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        let userArr = []
        try {
            axios.create({ withCredentials: true }).get(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/getMe`)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data.data.user) //object
                    userArr.push(res.data.data.user)
                    console.log(userArr)
                    setUser(userArr)
                    console.log(user)
                })

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }, [])

    const updatePassword = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            const res = await axios.create({ withCredentials: true }).patch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/updatePassword`, {
                currentPassword: currentPass,
                newPassword: newPass,
                passwordConfirm: confirmPass
            });
            if (!res) {
                return "not work"

            }
            console.log(res.data.data.user)
            navigate("/", { replace: true });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }



    return (
        <div className="account-container" >
            <div className="title-container">
                <p className="title">My Account</p>
            </div>
            <p className="sub-title">User information </p>
            <form className="form-user-information">
                <div className="div-form-user-information">
                    <label className="label-form-user-information">Username</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Username..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-user-information">
                    <label className="label-form-user-information">ssss</label>
                    <textarea placeholder={user.map(el => {
                        return el.email
                    })} />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-user-information">
                    <label className="label-form-user-information">First name</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="First name..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-user-information">
                    <label className="label-form-user-information">Last name</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Last name..." />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div className="buttom-line"></div>
            {/* //////CONTACT INFORMATION////////// */}
            <p className="sub-title-contact">CONTACT INFORMATION </p>
            <form className="form-contact-information">
                <div className="div-form-contact-information">
                    <label className="label-form-contact-information">Full Address</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Full Address..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-contact-information">
                    <label className="label-form-contact-information">City</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="City..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-contact-information">
                    <label className="label-form-contact-information">Country</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Country..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-contact-information">
                    <label className="label-form-contact-information">Postal code</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Postal code..." />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div className="buttom-line-contact"></div>
            {/* //////PASSWORD INFORMATION////////// */}
            <p className="sub-title-password">UPDATE PASSWORD </p>
            <form className="form-password-information">
                <div className="div-form-password-information">
                    <label className="label-form-password-information">Current Password</label>
                    <textarea onChange={(e) => setCurrentPass(e.target.value)} placeholder="Current Password..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-password-information">
                    <label className="label-form-password-information">New Password</label>
                    <textarea onChange={(e) => setNewPass(e.target.value)} placeholder="New Password..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-password-information">
                    <label className="label-form-password-information">Confirm Password</label>
                    <textarea onChange={(e) => setConfirmPass(e.target.value)} placeholder="Confirm Password..." />
                </div>
                <button onClick={(e) => updatePassword(e)} className="btn-update-pass">Update password</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Account;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do you know it's `undefined`? Based on the `console.log` after `setUser`?

Comment: when i map it in the html i get error state is undefined

Comment: In that case, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your post and comment, the issue seems to be that you are trying to access the value of the `user` state property before it is populated by the async axios call.

This is a common occurrence in React, and is quite simple to solve via conditional rendering.

**Example:**

```
{user === undefined
   ? <></> 
   : <textarea placeholder={user.map(el => {
        return el.email
     })} />
}
```

Or, instead of an empty fragment, you can put a loader/spinner or any other UI you'd like, in-order to let the user know that something is loading.

If you have more places where you try to access the value of `user`, you can use the conditional rendering there as-well.

Alternativaly, like [Matias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19272564/matias-bertoni) mentioned, you can put the condition before the "main" return of the component.
This is useful if you have multiple places where you need to access the value of `user` and you don't want to copy this logic for all of them.

**Example:**

```
if (user === undefined) {
   return <></>
}
return (
   ...
)
```

Comment: I also found that if I put in the useState of user [] its work also good                         
 const [user, setUser] = useState([ ]) like this

Comment: Yes, because if you declare a useState without a parameter, like this -> `useState()`, then it defaults to `undefined` as the initial value. If you pass it an empty array then it defaults to it instead. And trying to `.map` an empty array won't cause an error, it just won't render anything.

Comment: Either way you prefer, both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the state is not filled when the app is rendered. Try waiting for the axios request by adding a little `loading` system:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import './account.css'



function Account(props) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    const [currentPass, setCurrentPass] = useState()
    const [newPass, setNewPass] = useState()
    const [confirmPass, setConfirmPass] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) // add this



    let navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        let userArr = []
        try {
            axios.create({ withCredentials: true }).get(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/getMe`)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data.data.user) //object
                    userArr.push(res.data.data.user)
                    console.log(userArr)
                    setUser(userArr)
                    console.log(user)
                    setLoading(false) // and this
                })

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }, [])

    const updatePassword = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            const res = await axios.create({ withCredentials: true }).patch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/updatePassword`, {
                currentPassword: currentPass,
                newPassword: newPass,
                passwordConfirm: confirmPass
            });
            if (!res) {
                return "not work"

            }
            console.log(res.data.data.user)
            navigate("/", { replace: true });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }


    if(loading) return <p>loading</p> //and this...
    return (
        <div className="account-container" >
            <div className="title-container">
                <p className="title">My Account</p>
            </div>
            <p className="sub-title">User information </p>
            <form className="form-user-information">
                <div className="div-form-user-information">
                    <label className="label-form-user-information">Username</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Username..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-user-information">
                    <label className="label-form-user-information">ssss</label>
                    <textarea placeholder={user.map(el => {
                        return el.email
                    })} />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-user-information">
                    <label className="label-form-user-information">First name</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="First name..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-user-information">
                    <label className="label-form-user-information">Last name</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Last name..." />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div className="buttom-line"></div>
            {/* //////CONTACT INFORMATION////////// */}
            <p className="sub-title-contact">CONTACT INFORMATION </p>
            <form className="form-contact-information">
                <div className="div-form-contact-information">
                    <label className="label-form-contact-information">Full Address</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Full Address..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-contact-information">
                    <label className="label-form-contact-information">City</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="City..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-contact-information">
                    <label className="label-form-contact-information">Country</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Country..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-contact-information">
                    <label className="label-form-contact-information">Postal code</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Postal code..." />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div className="buttom-line-contact"></div>
            {/* //////PASSWORD INFORMATION////////// */}
            <p className="sub-title-password">UPDATE PASSWORD </p>
            <form className="form-password-information">
                <div className="div-form-password-information">
                    <label className="label-form-password-information">Current Password</label>
                    <textarea onChange={(e) => setCurrentPass(e.target.value)} placeholder="Current Password..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-password-information">
                    <label className="label-form-password-information">New Password</label>
                    <textarea onChange={(e) => setNewPass(e.target.value)} placeholder="New Password..." />
                </div>
                <div className="div-form-password-information">
                    <label className="label-form-password-information">Confirm Password</label>
                    <textarea onChange={(e) => setConfirmPass(e.target.value)} placeholder="Confirm Password..." />
                </div>
                <button onClick={(e) => updatePassword(e)} className="btn-update-pass">Update password</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Account;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: now work same problem